# Redirection with URL

Tags: regex, apache

I am trying to allow all the requests which are pointing to my website homepage. I have tried all the possible regex to match my scenario.

Ex: www.example.com/context ---> My homepage

I have tried all possibilities to get the expected result like below

resultRedirectMatch . https://example.com/context

resultRedirectMatch ^/(.*) www.example.com/context

and so on...

If anyone hits with www.example.com/*.html it should redirect to my homepage like below:

www.example.com/context

Any help can be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all your *.html to your homepage you could create a .htaccess file at your root directory with the following (make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on that server):

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteRule    "^/(.*)\.html$"  "/context" [R]
```

even though I find it difficult to think of a scenario when all the html files should redirect to your homepage.